# Entity Framework 6 Code First Approach and Database First Approach

Tags: .net, entity-framework

If my application has 30 tables and each table has atleast 1 million records, can I use Entity Framework Code First Approach? Based on my understanding, if any changes are to be made on any table, the database will be dropped and gets re-created. What is the right way to modify a table in EF code first approach without impacting the data?

Comment: You probably shouldn't try to force using "Code First" if you already have a database. You're pretty much already in the "Database First" boat.

It's going to be way easier for you if you just generate your dbcontext and run with that.

Comment: What EF version you are planning to use? EF 6 or EF Core?

Comment: We haven't decided on that. But it may be EF Core considering that is the latest.